# IQueryable.Any wrapper. Method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, iqueryable

I have this code:

```
public static bool ContainEx<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    return query.Any(expression);
}
```

If I use that:

```
return bonusesWhereSearch.WhereEx(x => userBonusesWhereSearch.ContainEx(y => y.Bonus_Id == x.Id));
```

I get this error message:

> System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
>   method 'Boolean
>   ContainEx[Bonus](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[SDataEntities.Bonus],
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[SDataEntities.Bonus,System.Boolean]])'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

and if I use `Any`:

```
return bonusesWhereSearch.WhereEx(x => userBonusesWhereSearch.Any(y => y.Bonus_Id == x.Id));
```

that does work.

Comment: use the code that works

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is, that entity framework doesn't execute `ContainEx`, but tries to translate this method into SQL. And since this is custom method translation fails. If you use `Any` directly, it is correctly translated to SQL equivalent.

Comment: how can i change my wrapper? I want user wrapper.